# Java null pointer exception while calling method in another class

Tags: java, oop

I have something similar to:

```
       public class A{
    public static B[] bObj;

    public A(){
        bObj = new B[2]; // create array of objects of class B
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        A aObj = new A();
        for(i=0;i<2;i++){
            bObj[i].testprint();
        }

    }
}

class B{
    public testprint(){
        System.out.println("Inside testprint()");
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get NullPointer exception at bObj[i].testprint(). I did do new B() in the constructor of A. But I don't know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Understand that initializing an array of reference, doesn't really initializes the references inside it. They are still `null`. You need to initialize them by iterating over the array.

```
public A(){
    bObj = new B[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < bObj.length; ++i) { bObj[i] = new B(); }
}
```